# React How to trigger page reload on state change

Tags: html, reactjs, reload

I want to reload my page when a state changes. Right now I am using the below code but don't know why it's reloading continuously even if the state is not changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  }, [state]);
```

Comment: This is a bad practice, what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` will always excute after first render,  and in your case even if `state` doesn't change it will reload the page on first render. i think you should add check in `useEffect` something like this

```
function YourComponent(){
    const initialState = "initial state";
    const [state, changeState] = useState(initialState);
    useEffect(()=>{
        // on first render, state will be initial state, so it will 
        // not reload, but on subsequent state change, it will reload the page
        if(state!==initialState){
            window.location.reload()
        }
    }, [state]);
}
```